The zero-state response of a linear-constant-coefficient-differential-equations (LCCDE) with non-zero initial conditions
I have started to learn about signals and systems, and my textbook is the second edition of Signals & System by Alan Oppenheim. I got really confused about the solution of linear constant coefficient differential equations (LCCDE) with non-zero initial conditions, especially the part related to the definition of zero-state response. In most scenarios, the meaning of zero-state response seems to be unambiguous, but when it appears together with causality, some concepts are difficult to understand.
Based on the author's description, two conclusions can be drawn (I quoted descriptions of the author and put them in the appendix, which is also the basis for the following two conclusions):

If the system represented by LCCDE satisfies the initial rest condition(if x(t) = 0 for t < t0 , then y(t) must also equal 0 fort < t0), it must be a causal linear time-invariant system, otherwise it is an incremental linear system. The incremental linear system response consists of zero state and response and zero input response.

The zero-state response corresponds to a system with no initial energy storage, which is the response of a causal LTI system caused only by input, while the zero input response is a linear function of the initial condition.


For a system represented by LCCDE, assume that the input is added at time 0 and y(0-)=c. If the above conclusions 1. and 2. are correct, then when calculating the zero-state response, since the system satisfies causality, linearity and time-invariance at the same time, the default initial condition is yzs (0-)=0; and when calculating the zero-input response, the default initial condition is yzi(0-)=c? (It seems that all examples are calculated in this way, for example ,Linear Constant Coefficient Differential Equations: Zero-Input and Zero-State responses)
But an obvious counterexample is the unit impulse response h(t) of the LTI system. h(t) is the response caused only by the input, that is, the unit impulse signal. At this time, the system has no initial energy storage. It is obviously not a zero-input response, but a zero-state response of the LTI system. However, in the chapter realated to Laplace transform, many examples show that h(t) can be a bilateral signal, that is, a non-causal system also has a zero-state response.
In the definition of the zero-state response,why does the author believe that it must correspond to the response of a causal LTI system? In the second edition of Signals & System, zero-state response and zero-input response are proposed for linear incremental systems, in which  the "incremental linearity" and causality should be independent. If the zero-state response is not limited to the causal system, then when solving the zero-state response, is it wrong to default the condition yzs (0-) = 0? In other words, when using a constant coefficient linear differential equation to solve the unit impulse response h(t), if h(t) is a non-causal signal, then substituting h(0-) = 0 for the solution seems to be wrong. If the system is non-causal, for a specific constant coefficient linear differential equation, the initial condition y(0-)=c contains the joint contribution of the system's initial energy storage and the response caused by the input, and it seemd to be wrong to default the condition yzs (0-) = 0.
(One possibility is that the author defaults to only considering causal systems, but I think the probability of this possibility is not high, because I can feel that the author is limiting the scope of the system discussed in his textbook in a rigorous way. When the author introduced the concepts of zero input and zero state, he limited them only by "system represented by a linear constant coefficient differential equation of the form...")
In summary, I got confused about:

What is the definition of zero-state response?
Does the scope of zero-state response include non-causal systems?
If 2 is correct, why does the author limit the scope of zero-state response to causal system,or why does the author think that the zero-state response of a linear incremental system must correspond to the response of a causal LTI system，why not non-causal LTI?
If 2 is correct, please give an example to show the process of solving the unit impulse response of a non-causal system, that is, the process of solving differential equations;
Can we conclude that: a linear constant coefficient differential equation(LCCDE) with the initial rest condition represents a causal LTI system; and a LCCDE that does not satisfy the initial rest condition must be a linear incremental system, but not necessarily a causal system. That is, the system represented by LCCDE can be regarded as a superposition of a linear system and a zero input response (as shown in Figure 1.48, see Appendix), in which the causality of linear system (that is, the part corresponding to the zero state response) needs to be judged based on initial conditions, while the zero input response and the initial condition satisfy a linear relationship.


Supplement
I quote two places where the author introduces zero-input response and zero-state response to solve LCCDE.
The first place is the note at the bottom in Page 120:

If the initial condition for eq. (2.95) is nonzero, the resulting
system is incrementally linear. That is, the overall response can be
viewed, much as in Figure 1.48, as the superposition of the
response to the initial conditions alone (with input set to 0) and the
response to the input with an initial condition of 0 (i.e:, the
response of the causal LTI system described by eq. (2.95)).

In which, the author mentioned eq. (2.95) is a first-order constant coefficient differential equation:



and content related Figure 1.48 is as follows:

The second place is Example 9.38 in P719, where the author mentioned as follow.

In which, the eq. (9.189) is as follow:

Note that

Furthermore, eq. (9.197) illustrates an important fact about the
solution of linear constant-coefficient differential equations with
nonzero initial conditions, namely, that the overall response is
simply the superposition of the zero-state and the zero-input
responses. The zero-state response is the response obtained by setting
the initial conditions to zero-i.e., it is the response of an LTI
system defined by the differential equation and the condition of
initial rest.


The zero-input response is the response to the initial conditions with
the input set to zero. The zero-input response is a linear function of
the values of the initial conditions (e.g., doubling the values of
both β and γ doubles the zero-input response).




What is the definition of zero-state response?


Zero-state response is the system's response to an external input when the system is in zero-state (all initial conditions are set to zero).


Does the scope of zero-state response include non-causal systems?


Yes.


If 2 is correct, why does the author limit the scope of zero-state response to causal system,or why does the author think that the zero-state response of a linear incremental system must correspond to the response of a causal LTI system，why not non-causal LTI?


The author likely scopes the subject to causal systems because non-causal systems are not realizable. Just like it is always assumed that the order of $Q(D)$ is higher than or equal to the order of $P(D)$ in $Q(D)y(t) = P(D)x(t)$.


If 2 is correct, please give an example to show the process of solving the unit impulse response of a non-causal system, that is, the process of solving differential equations;


This system is non causal: $y'(t) = x(t+1) $. If the input is an impulse we have
$$h'(t) = \delta(t+1)$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{t}h'(\tau) \: \text{d}\tau =  \int_{-\infty}^{t}\delta(\tau+1) \: \text{d}\tau$$
$$h(t) = u(t+1) $$


Can we conclude that: a linear constant coefficient differential equation(LCCDE) with the initial rest condition represents a causal LTI system; and a LCCDE that does not satisfy the initial rest condition must be a linear incremental system, but not necessarily a causal system. That is, the system represented by LCCDE can be regarded as a superposition of a linear system and a zero input response (as shown in Figure 1.48, see Appendix), in which the causality of linear system (that is, the part corresponding to the zero state response) needs to be judged based on initial conditions, while the zero input response and the initial condition satisfy a linear relationship.


This I don't know the answer to.
